# Unable to debug "Delete method of Range class failed"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete select ranges and shift the rest of the cells up but keep getting stuck on the following error

Run-time error '1004':

Unable to debug "Delete method of Range class failed"

I can't see what exactly I'm doing wrong, would appreciate any pointers.

```
Mainfile = "Travelex Order.xls"
SecFile = "EURUSD.xls"
SheetOne = "Bulk Order"
SheetTwo = "EURUSD Breakdown"
SheetThree = "PDF Gen2"
SheetFour = "EURUSD"
SheetFive = "Rate Check"

Workbooks(Mainfile).Worksheets(SheetOne).Range("A23:C96").Copy
Workbooks(Mainfile).Worksheets(SheetFive).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Count = 2

Do
    If Workbooks(Mainfile).Worksheets(SheetFive).Range("A" & Count).Value <> "" And Workbooks(Mainfile).Worksheets(SheetFive).Range("B" & Count).Value = "" And Workbooks(Mainfile).Worksheets(SheetFive).Range("C" & Count).Value = "" Then

        Workbooks(Mainfile).Worksheets(SheetFive).Range("A" & Count & ":C" & Count).Delete Shift:=xlToUp

    End If
    Count = Count + 1
Loop Until Count > 80
```

I tried doing the following change but have had no luck

```
Workbooks(Mainfile).Worksheets(SheetFive).Range("A" & Count & ":C" & Count).Delete Shift:=xlToUp
```

to

```
Range("A" & Count & ":C" & Count).Delete Shift:=xlToUp
```

I always keep getting an error on that line.

Comment: Try `Range(Cells(Count, 1), Cells(Count, 3))` (This is easier to read). You should also qualify these ranges. I also think that `xlToUp` looks strange. You sure thats the correct operator? I believe it should be `xlShiftUp`

Comment: Shifting up is the default. You can probably get away with removing the `Shift:= ...` part and just have your delete line

Comment: It's `xlUp` not `xlToUp`.

Comment: `Option Explicit` is your friend in these cases. This should have highlighted that error when you first tried to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've messed up the Syntax as commented by Rory, it should be xlUp.